# Creating network files in SUMO using NETCONVERT

Tags: sumo

Problem when calling netconvert in sumo:

I am trying to create my own scenario for simulation purposes. 
I am using OpenStreetMaps for this.

```
python osmWebWizard.py
```

opens the browser and I select the area which I download.

```
netconvert --osm-files osm_bbox.osm.xml -o osm.net.xml
```

The error message I get is

```
Error: Cannot import network data without PROJ-Library. Please install packages proj before building sumo
Warning: Environment variable SUMO_HOME is not set, using built in type maps.
Quitting (on error).
```

My attempt to fix the problem is:

```
sudo apt-get install libproj*
```

But it seems like a dead end there and I am out of options.

Thank you.

**EDIT**
I have a gut feeling it has to do with *libproj0* not being available anymore.

Comment: It would be helpful if you mention your operating system with the version.

Comment: Linux Mint and Sumo 0.26.0

Comment: Is this a self compiled sumo or is it from a ppa / the standard distribution?

Comment: Have you added SUMO_HOME to your environment? If you type sumo in the shell/command prompt window, what do you see?